# difference between output of df and blkid

Tags: disk-usage

When I run `blkid` I get

```
/dev/vda1   ...etc
/dev/vda2   ...etc
```

However, when I run `df -h` I do not see the second drive. I only see

```
/dev/vda1  ...etc 
/devtmpfs   ...etc
```

Is this because df only shows file systems that are mounted, and the vda2 drive is not mounted? Can you help me understand the difference between the two and why df -h doesnt show the second drive vda2 ?

Comment: forgive me for a dumb question but, are you saying that, or the man page is insinuating that, since the drive is not mounted it has no name?

Comment: what is the prefered, or easiest method to list either all file systems, or something to show filesystems that are not mounted?

Comment: is blkid or lsblk the best, or something like fdisk -l ?

Comment: 1. `df` shows only *mounted* file systems; 2. Different tools are 'best' for different purposes, maybe you will find `lsblk` best for this particular purpose (to list all file systems and show if they are mounted). It will show all drives and partitions, not only those with file systems, but also a swap partition, an extended partition, and a partition that is not yet formatted.

Answer (score 2):

From the relevant man pages:

"***blkid* - locate/print block device attributes**"

"***df* - report file system disk space usage**"

So ***df*** tells you about disk space usage of the filesystems ***on those block devices***.

In response to your supplementary comments on your question, it's not that either is "***best***" per se, they are different tools.

Comment: @Oscalation- If this answered your question, good practice to mark as ***answered** to preclude others revisiting a resolved issue.  Thanks- T

Answer (score 0):

In short

- **`df`** shows the mounted file systems and details about them
- **`blkid`** shows the block devices (drives, partitions) that are found and details about them
- **`lsblk`** can give you a good overview of both

  ```
  sudo lsblk -fm  # in a wide terminal window
  ```

or, if your terminal window is not wide enough, for example only 80 columns

```
    sudo lsblk -f
    sudo lsblk -m
```

or, if you want to skip some details,

```
    sudo lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint
```